# calling kubectl version on Google Cloud Terminal takes ~30 seconds and returns "Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp ... timeout"

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl

I am doing some tutorials from https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-springboot-kubernetes?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Flearn%2Fpathways%2Fjava-cloud-fundamentals%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fcodelabs.developers.google.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fcloud-springboot-kubernetes#5. I am using Google Cloud Console. When I type:

```
kubectl version
```

I am getting an response:

```
WARNING: This version information is deprecated and will be replaced with the output from kubectl version --short.  Use --output=yaml|json to get the full version.
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"27", GitVersion:"v1.27.2", GitCommit:"7f6f68fdabc4df88cfea2dcf9a19b2b830f1e647", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-05-17T14:20:07Z", GoVersion:"go1.20.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Kustomize Version: v5.0.1
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 34.135.56.138:443: i/o timeout
```

What I do not like is the

```
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 34.135.56.138:443: i/o timeout
```

I am getting this error also when running other **kubectl** commands, which stops my progress.
I am using only out of the box tools provided by Google Cloud.
What is causing this error in Google Cloud Console? Do I need to make additional Kubernetes configuration? (The tutorial did not mention anything like that)

---

Running the command as suggested in the comments:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials hello-java-cluster --zone=us-central1-c
```

I am getting an error:

```
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) ResponseError: code=404, message=Not found: projects/question-tracker/zones/us-central1-c/clusters/hello-java-cluster.
No cluster named 'hello-java-cluster' in question-tracker.
```

EDIT:
I have run the command: (instead of **hello**-java-cluster I ran it with previously created **questy**-java-cluster)

```
(quizdev)$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials  questy-java-cluster --zone=us-central1-c
```

And it ran without error giving result:

```
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
kubeconfig entry generated for questy-java-cluster.
```

After this operation kubectl version runs in 1 second and does not give the error.

Comment: There are 2 steps that get blurred by `gcloud` into one. The `gcloud container clusters create` command not only creates the cluster but it also configures `kubectl` via kubeconfig (`~/.kube/config`) to access the cluster. If you're unable to e.g. `kubectl get nodes` after `gcloud container clusters create` and you're confident the cluster created successfully (i.e. by checking Cloud Console), it may be that the kubeconfig file was not correctly configured.

Comment: Please confirm that the kubeconfig file in the default location (`~/.kube/config`) exists and contains data (`cluster`, `server`, `user`) entries correspondonging to your cluster. **DON'T** post the file here as it contains confidential information.

Comment: If that all looks good, you can try repeating the step that configures kubeconfig: `gcloud container clusters get-credentials hello-java-cluster --zone=us-central1-c`. If there are any other errors running these commands, please edit your question and include the errors.

Comment: the config file exists and contains section wit clusters and users. every cluster has a server property.  I do not see there a cluster which I have created before though. This cluster is visible in dashboard (gui) but not in the config file. running gcloud container .... command returns error. I will paste it into the question

Comment: I have run the command with other cluster: (instead of hello-java-cluster I ran it with previously created questy-java-cluster) and it solved my issue. DazWiikin if you would like you can post an answer to the question and I will accept it for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 steps that get blurred by `gcloud` into one.

The [`gcloud container clusters create`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/create) command not only creates the cluster but it also configures `kubectl` via kubeconfig (`~/.kube/config`) to access the cluster.

If you're unable to e.g. `kubectl get nodes` after `gcloud container clusters create` and you're confident the cluster created successfully (i.e. by checking Cloud Console), it may be that the kubeconfig file was not correctly configured.

Please confirm that the kubeconfig file in the default location (~/.kube/config) exists and contains data (`cluster`, `server`, `user`) entries correspondonging to your cluster.

If that all looks good, you can try repeating the step that configures kubeconfig: [`gcloud container clusters get-credentials hello-java-cluster --zone=us-central1-c`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/get-credentials). If there are any other errors running these commands, please edit your question and include the errors.

If you've changed the cluster's `{NAME}`, `{LOCATION}` or are using a different Google Cloud `{PROJECT}`, please use these (replacing with the correct values) in the above command:

```bash
gcloud container clusters get-credentials ${NAME} \
--location=${LOCATION} \
--project=${PROJECT}
```